# Pasar parametros desde un res.render

Tags: nodejs, express

Buenos días necesito pasar parámetros a mi una función Express app.get desde un res.render. La verdad es la primera vez que se me ocurre y no tengo la minima idea de como hacerlo. 
En esta linea de código debería pasar un parámetro;

```
   `res.render("usuarios", tipos);`
```

y en mi función debería obtenerla:

```
    app.get("/usuarios", (req, res) => {
        let tipo: req.params.tipo;
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328028/node-js-passing-parameters-to-client-via-express-render/29328530

Comment: perdon @pedro buccellati estas confundido res.render se utiliza para renderizar alguna vista y para llamar a una ruta debes realizar un request, tu código deberías ponerlo en una función aparte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres añadir parámetros a un resp, que renderice una página, los pones entre llaves, así:

```
app.get("/usuarios", (req, res) => {
     resp.render("usuarios", {tipos});
});
```